# Hosting Neo4J Browser Separately From Server

Tags: azure, neo4j, azure-web-app-service

I want to have three different Neo4J instances running (each with a different database). Then I need three different Neo4J browser visualizers (think project1.domainname.com / project2.domainname.com / project3.domainname.com) with each one mapping to a specific database instance

I've managed to get the three different database instances running on a single Azure VM - so far so good.

But I'm not sure how to create and map those browsers. I'd like to run them each as Azure websites as that would help with some other problems I've forseen.

1) Where is this browser HTML etc. so I can load it to the Azure Website?

2) Where in that code would I specify the IP Address and Port that browser should be talking to?

I've also heard some people talking about an Azure for Neo4J project but that is nearly five years old and the Neo4J guys said to put the database instances on VM's. Were they right>

Answer (score 5):

The Neo4j Browser is an angular app that you can find in the neo4j source code at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3/community/browser

You can set the host that the browser app can talk to:

`:config host:"http://host:port"`

This is an undocumented feature and might be removed.

For 3.0 the intent is to decouple browser and Neo4j anyway.

Comment: I've downloaded the source. In what folder/file is the :config host located? I can't find it with a text search.