# Syntax for Connecting to Neo4J Database on Separate Machine

Tags: neo4j

This question is actually an outgrowth of this one. [Hosting Neo4J Browser Separately From Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887772/hosting-neo4j-browser-separately-from-server)

Here’s the project goal – it’s still valid -

*I want to have three different Neo4J instances running (each with a different database). Then I need three different Neo4J browser visualizers (think project1.domainname.com / project2.domainname.com / project3.domainname.com) with each one mapping to a specific database instance
I've managed to get the three different database instances running on a single Azure VM - so far so good.*

**UPDATE**

I have three instances of the Browsers running on Azure websites. But I’m still finding it impossible to connect to any of the databases.

The previous poster suggested “:config host:http://host:port” which I’ve tried to no avail.

So questions –

1)  The browser is suggesting I use the command “:server connect” rather than “:config host”. Is this the better command to go with? If so what’s the syntax for using it? Is there a link anywhere in the documentation that describes all these commands? I can see the documentation to alter the config files but not the commands that run in real time.

2)  When the browser is disconnected from the server I can see the following information.

[image]

When it’s connected (to local host) I get this.

[image]

It seems strange to me. I thought I was telling the browser to connect to a remote server in which case it wouldn’t be talking directly to a file location. Is this file location just the remote server telling me what local file source it’s working from?

3)  Are there any log files being generated by any of these connection attempts? I’m sure if I could get something better than “Check the cord” I would have any idea of where to look?

***Update 2***

The bit about using the HTML inspector was key. Clearing the disconnected message now lets me see what I'm doing. I've dropped the firewalls on the VM that's hosting the Neo4J server and I can at least now send it a command in Fiddler and I'm getting something back so the network issues seem to be cleared.

But for each step forward I seem to be going two steps back. Now when I issue the config host command I'm getting incessant requests that I log into the database. The default username and passwords are not working. It keeps insisting that "No authorization header supplied".

[image]

I've tried a clean copy of Enterprise 2.3.1

I go into neo4j-server.properties and change dbms.security.auth_enabled=true to false. Then I execute the startup PowerShell script (derived from here - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/powershell.html)

```
Import-Module C:\Data\Neo4j-1\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1 

'C:\Data\Neo4j-1' |
Initialize-Neo4jServer `
-ListenOnIPAddress 0.0.0.0 `
-HTTPPort 7474 `
-OnlineBackupServer '127.0.0.1:6362' `
-PassThru |
Start-Neo4jServer -Console
```

and the script seems to be writing to the config file and changing the auth setting back to true. I tried setting the config file to read only and the PowerShell script bombs claiming it needs write access to the file.

I'm assuming the script is overriding what's in the config file and there must be some sort of switch I can put in the script to turn auth to false.

Comment: The bit about using the HTML inspector was key - now I can see what I'm doing. I've dropped the firewalls on the VM that's hosting the Neo4J server and I can at least now send it a command in Fiddler and I'm getting something back.

But for each step forward I seem to be going two steps back. Not I'm getting incessent requests that I log into teh database. The default username and passwords are not working. It keep insisting that "No authorization header supplied"

Comment: I also had the "no-auth-header" supplied once, can you try to run it in incognito mode? Seems to be an issue with storage or aggressive caching of the Web-Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your firewalls to allow port 7474 ? And did you configure neo4j-server.properties to listen on interface `0.0.0.0`

I just tried it with. `:config host:"http://myhost.com:7474"`
and it worked well.

The not-connected error is a bit annoying, you can remove it by using the html inspector and removing the div

1. not that I know (except with :help server)
2. It is the file of the remote server
3. http logs in the web-browser / browser-console

Comment: The element inspector thing was key. But as you can see above (Update 2) there are more problems coming up.